# Open only files containing dates of past seven days in filename

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a directory containing subdirectories and all of them contain files having the following name structure:

```
daily_report_yyy-mm-dd.csv
```

where `yyyy-mm-dd` are dates since the beginning of 2020 with frequency 1 (day).

In one project, I only need the files referring to the past seven days and I therefore see no use reading all files and then slicing the resulting dataframe. This script does jsut this, reads all files and concatenates them into onle single df

```
path = path_to_downloads
extension = '.csv'
files_w_path =[]
for root, dirs_list, files_list in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in files_list:
        if os.path.splitext(file_name)[-1] == extension:
            file_name_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
            files_w_path.append(file_name_path)

df = []
for filename in files_w_path:
    df.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
vehicle = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```

Now, I would like to use the date at which the script is executed and find all the files that contain that day as part of the name as well as all seven days prior to that date. I have thought about using the following code, but I have no idea about how to proceed.

```
base = datetime.date.today()

list_of_files =[]
for date in pd.date_range(base, base-7, freq='D').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):
    for file_name in files[files.str.contains(date)]:
        list_of_files.append(filename)
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so you just want a function that parses a given directory and returns a list of all the filenames that are seven days old or newer?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try to make this robust you should take advantage of using the built-in `datetime` library and pattern match on the file names using `re`. If something doesn't match the expected pattern then you can print the file name and investigate further. The function below should give you what you want.

```
import datetime
import os
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=daily_report_)[0-9-]+(?=\.csv)")

def valid_files(path):
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    now = datetime.date.today()
    threshold = now - delta
    output = []

    for _, _, files in os.walk(path):
        for fin in files:
            if fin.endswith(".csv"):
                try:
                    ts = ts_parser(fin)
                # catch regex and date parsing errors
                except (IndexError, ValueError):
                    print(f"{fin} does not match the pattern")
                    continue
                if ts >= threshold:
                    output.append(fin)
    
    return output


def ts_parser(fname):
    matched = pattern.search(fname).group(0)
    ts = datetime.datetime.date(
        datetime.datetime.strptime(matched, "%Y-%m-%d")
    )
    return ts
```

Suppose I have a directory with the following structure.

```
so/
├── daily_report_2020-09-21.csv
├── daily_report_2021-04-04.csv
├── daily_report_2021-04-05.csv
├── daily_report_2021-04-06.csv
├── daily_report_2021-04-12.csv
```

When I run the function as shown below we get the desired results.

```
valid_files("./so/")
>> ['daily_report_2021-04-06.csv',
    'daily_report_2021-04-12.csv',
    'daily_report_2021-04-05.csv']
```

Comment: you're welcome, please be aware I excluded timezones so the dates here are naive, there are edge cases that could trip you up, for example running this when the clocks move forward or back because of daylight savings.

Answer (score 1):

I've also implemented the answer using regex and pathlib library.

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re
regex = re.compile(".{1,}\\d{4,4}\\-(0{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\\-(0{0,1}[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$")

path = Path('.')

result = []
delta = timedelta(days=7)
for csv_file in path.glob("**/*.csv"):
    matchArray = regex.findall(csv_file.stem)
    if len(matchArray)> 0:
        file_date = datetime.strptime(csv_file.stem[-10:], '%Y-%m-%d')
        if file_date.date() > datetime.now().date() - delta:
            result.append(csv_file.absolute()) # if you need relative path use result.append(csv_file)

print(result)
```

you can specify the path in Path constructor - Path().

```
Path('.') means the path of the current working directory where the python is located.
```

Now, Extract all the CSV files from the directory and all the subdirectories.

```
path.glob('**/*.csv')-
```

It'll return the generator object. Therefore, it's fast if you have got a large number of CSV files.
Using regex to match the file pattern you specified above and only processing filtered CSV files.
Then, I've used timedelta function to check for the latest files.
Finally, results are appended to the list result.

Comment: why redefine constants such as `timedelta(days=7)` every loop?

Comment: define `timedelta` itself once, not the calculation

Comment: Ohh that make sense @gold_cy

Comment: String slicing will not fail as I'm checking the exact format in regex and only processing those files which match the pattern. @gold_cy. Will appreciate it if you give me any example where it might fail.

Comment: @gold_cy added timedelta fix suggested by you :)

Comment: that's assuming that every file is formatted properly, what if whoever is supplying the file mistypes something such as filename, that won't be captured

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231043/discussion-between-nk03-and-gold-cy).